# "Success" or "successes"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number

Which is correct?

> The newspaper described the **success** of people like Bob and Joe.
>
> The newspaper described the **successes** of people like Bob and Joe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, since *[success](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/success)* can be used as a countable or uncountable noun.

Comment: Which one do you think sounds better?

Comment: "The success of" is much more common and sounds more natural to me: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+success+of%2C+the+successes+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 . You would use successes of if you were pointing out two distinct kinds of success, though.

Comment: +1  I would favour successes in contexts where I was also acknowledging the failures either explicitly or (thouh less likely) implicitly, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but have slightly different meanings.

"Describing the success" of someone has a more general tone. For instance, the article might discuss Bob's overall career - e.g. "he rose to the top of his company and turned it into the worldwide market leader it is today."

"Describing the successes" of someone implies a discussion of each particular triumph. For instance, the article might discuss particular events in Bob's career - e.g. "his high-quality tender won his company the crucial widget contract with GloboCorp. He then was selected as team leader despite being the youngest on his team."

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct in their own sense.

*Success* can be pronounced as the dual meaning to target one or more than one person i.e., countable as mentioned above.